# jquery validate form after being cloned.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup `<div>` which clones a hidden form and inserts this into the popup. Due to this being dynamically inserted I am not able to get the validate plugin to work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MbNCh/1/
You will see that the inline form is validating perfectly altough if you click the popup link this form is not validating.

You can see that I am calling the plugin like this:

```
$page.find("form.validate").simpleValidate(simple_validate_options);
$popup.find("form.validate").simpleValidate(simple_validate_options);
```

Also is there anyway I can merge both the cached `$page` and `$popup` together?.

Comment: You need to call `$popup.find("form.validate").simpleValidate(simple_validate_options);` only after (and every time) you open/create the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are appending the cloned form on open popup link click event you should call `simpleValidate` plugin inside the click event after appending the html into popup content.

Here is the working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MbNCh/2/